# Which port should i open on firewall if i want to connect to AS400 machine

Tags: port, ibm-midrange

Should I have to open all [these ports](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/toolbox/faq/ports.html) on firewall to connect to `AS400` machine?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Just like all other types of servers (Windows, UNIX/Linux, mainframe, whatever), yes, you need a lot of ports open to connect to a lot of different services. In order to know **which** ports you need open, we need to know which services you'll connect to. This work should be done by a network admin.

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to the AS/400 using the Java toolbox classes, then you need at least:

- 449 - as-svrmap - This is the port mapper service.  It tells the toolbox client which port is used by which service.  According to the notes, you can skip this if you specify the ports from within the connection, but that's not something I've ever done.  I always just keep this port open in the firewall and let the system do its thing instead of trying to work around it.
- 8470 - as-central - This is used to create code page conversion tables.  It's best to just keep this port open, too.
- 8476 - as-signon - You need this one so you can authenticate.

Beyond that, the chart referenced in your question covers the ports you need.  It all depends on what services you plan to use.  If it's just calling programs or commands, then you need port 8475 (as-rmtcmd).  If you're accessing data queues, then you need 8472 (in addition to the three mentioned above).

Comment: Thank You. Good explanation.